# Embed javascript with jslink

Tags: javascript, jslink

I have a simple javascript demo file [demo.js], stored in the  [sitecollection]/[site]/SiteAssets/Scripts directory:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var today = new Date();
            document.write("<p> Today is: " + today.toString() + "</p>");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I put the code into a SEWP, it delivers the defined output. However if I put the link ~/SitesAssets/Scripts/demo.js into the jslink of a task list, nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't make an html file, just a javascript file without the html, body or script tags.

```
alert('jslink in da house!');
```